# SQL Query by a foreign key which needs to be filtered by a value in different table and column

Tags: sql

I have two tables X and Y:

- `X` has columns `ID` (primary key), `Name`
- `Y` has a foreign key to `X` referencing the `ID` column

I can only get the Name value from an input.

I need to get all rows in Y which match the Name as found in  X

How do I write this SQL query?

I have been through a few tutorial by I am unable to understand how to achieve this. Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: This is called a join and where clause (SQL 101), any basic tutorial (such as http://www.sql-join.com/) will show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * 
from y 
left join x on x.id = y.xid 
where x.name = @nameparameter
```

A query like above should do the job. I can explain further if you will

Comment: Is there a column named 'clinic'?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the attributes of 'y', use

```
select y.* from y join x on y.x = x.id where x.name = 'your desired name'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Y.[Id], Y.[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Y]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[X] ON [Y].ForeignKeyId = X.Id
WHERE X.Name LIKE '%YOUR_Query%'
```